# Looking for a musically oriented outline of analog signal processing circuits

Tags: recommendations, books

Is there a musically oriented outline of analog signal processing circuit design?

My final goal is to be able to design and build pedals for me and my friends.

I know the basic physics of electric circuits and i have an extensive math background. That's why I'm looking for a book that doesn't shy away from the technicalities.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. I have designed and built analogue pedals for nearly 30 years - and the maths and physics bit is essential, but I can't understand what your first sentence is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find some of what you seek [here](http://www.muzique.com/') or [here](http://www.diystompboxes.com/pedals/schematics.html) or if you really like Bose stuff [here](http://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/s/guitar-effect-schematics.php) and one more to the list [here](http://www.beavisaudio.com/projects/).

All these links offer schematics which is all you need to start building as for comprehensive literature [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0825695023) may be a nice guide (but i have never read it so I don't know).

Just a word from an electrical engineer. Being a good circuit designer, or for that matter being a circuit designer at all takes a lot more than the basic understandings of the physics of circuits even though its important. While high school physics will get you to the point of building some great passive filters and maybe a few other things there is more to it than that. While important the physics will be a solid basis but formal electrical engineering training may help you a great deal. I might advise a book on circuits like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195323033) (its the one I used back in college, good book) to build a basic understanding of electronics.

Please don't take this as a discouragement I only mean to encourage you to learn more about circuits to get to the point where you can take on a project like this. Seeing building and designing effects as an end goal is a good way to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

A huge amount of information can be bought from here:

http://electronotes.netfirms.com

but you will need to have a fair knowledge of analogue devices and circuit theory.  You'll probably also have to rework the circuits with up to date components.